# Least characters in a numerical representation of integers

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle, recreational-mathematics

I was wondering what the shortest way to represent any given number is. For example, $387420489=9^9$. So, for this case, the smallest representation is of order 2 (2 numbers). Alternatively, $10=2\cdot5$ also has 2, but it began with 2, so there is nothing constructive there.

The symbols permitted in the expression are $+,-,\times$ and taking exponential is also permitted.

Edit: To make this into a question, is there a general form to numbers that have a least character representation that is less than their natural representation?

Comment: Although for any given number one can search, I don't see a way to answer the question in general.  What are you looking for?

Comment: @Ross, is there any interest in this type of problem? I was looking for a general solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not allowing division?

Comment: One could certainly write a program to generate all the strings that involve a given number of digits and evaluate them, giving the list of numbers expressible by that many digits.  I do not see a general solution to finding that $5686676=7^8-5^7$ for example

Comment: @Robert, I have no good reason. If that were allowed though, I would not know how to answer why no $!$ or something else more fun. Perhaps the $-$ was a bad idea.

Comment: What Ross has said. I note that the smallest (positive integer) number that has a representation shorter than just writing it in decimal is $125=5^3$, followed by $128=2^7$, $216=6^3$, $243=3^5$, $256=2^8=4^4$, $343=7^3$, $512=2^9=8^3$, $625=5^4$, $729=3^6=9^3$.

Comment: @Ross, I hope the edit helps.

Comment: The sequence of numbers @Gerry gave is in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A104233).

Comment: @J.M. Yes you are correct, but the sequence given in the OEIS is more restrictive as they allow a lot more parameters. Namely, they allow division and bracketing. However, that being said, I think finding a general form may be too tricky

Comment: To make this interesting you should allow division and bracketing, and only allow the digit 1. In that case I think that the expansion of the prime factorization may be the shortest expression.